# date label on x-axis python format

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

My data looks something like this

```
01.03.20    10
02.03.20    10
04.03.20    15
05.03.20    16
```

I want to plot the `dates` vs the `y` values and I want the format of the `xaxis` to be something similar to `Mar 01` `Mar 02` `Mar 03` ...

Here's my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=100, c='C0')
ax.plot(x, y, ls='-', c='C0')


# Set the locator
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
# Specify the format - %b gives us Jan, Feb...
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%d')

X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
# Specify formatter
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
```

Something is wrong as the `x-axis`, `xticks`, and `xlabel` is not showing. How can I change the format of the `xlabel` to show the month and the date eg: `Mar 01` `Mar 02` `Mar 03` ...

Comment: what is the output of your code? please paste an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I assume your `x` axis contains `string`, not `datetime`. Then, before plotting I would convert it as below.

```
x=[datetime.strptime(xi, "%d.%m.%y") for xi in x]
```

2) If you select `MonthLocator`, you cannot get it as Mar 01... Thus, switch it with a `DayLocator`.

```
locator = mdates.DayLocator()
```

3) This one is optional to have cleaner code. You don't need `X`.

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
```

Sample code is here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime

x=["01.03.20", "02.03.20", "04.03.20", "05.03.20"]
x=[datetime.strptime(xi, "%d.%m.%y") for xi in x]
y=[10, 10, 15,16]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=100, c='C0')
ax.plot(x, y, ls='-', c='C0')

locator = mdates.DayLocator() 
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%d')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
ax.set_xlim(x[0],x[3])

plt.show()
```

Sample result is here.

[image]